# How to parse images in json from html page

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I need to parse images from 500px and show it in my android application. But all trys get me an error: "json parse error unrecognized token '<'". How can i fetch just src for images?

I don't know much about this, serfing internet don't help at all, try a bunch of combinations using fetch function.

```
webCall=()=>{

        return fetch('https://500px.com/popular')
               .then((response) => response.json())
               .then((responseJson) => {
                 this.setState({
                   isLoading: false,
                   dataSource: responseJson
                 }, function() {
                   // In this block you can do something with new state.
                 });
               })
               .catch((error) => {
                 console.error(error);
               });

       }
```

Comment: If your request is returning HTML, you cannot treat it like a JSON response.

Comment: Fetching that url returns a string of the page's HTML, not a JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://500px.com/popular returns an HTML page, not an image. The `unrecognized token '<'` refers to the first character of the opening tag received from the page (likely `<!DOCTYPE>`. Parsing HTML as JSON doesn't work.

It looks like 500px [closed their public API](https://support.500px.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002435653-API-) recently, so you might be out of luck.

Comment: It's a bit sad, because it was task for android developer in my town. So it's no chance to take photos from 500px having permission only to html page?

Comment: To my knowledge, the only proper way to get images from this site would be through the API. You could look into other similar sites to see if they have an open API.